# Javascript array dynamic population

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-arrays

I am brand new in WebDevelopment and I came across the following issue.
 I have an html file where a textbox is defined as well as a "View all Contents" button

1. The user can enter a value in the textbox and submit the data
2. Then repeat this action multiple times
3. Every time a new value is entered this value should be stored to a
   Javascript array
4. The user will be able to view the contents of the Javascript array
   when clicking on the button "View all Contents".

So my problem is how these values are stored dynamically in Javascript and printed when the user is finished.

Your answer is very much appreciated.

Best Regards

Olga

Comment: Add items to an array with `array.push()`... are you using ajax to submit? A page refresh will destroy your array.

Answer (score 1):

A very trivial example: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/unEMp/.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox">
<br>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
<br>
<input type="button" id="view" value="View all Contents">
```

with:

```
var arr = []; // the array

document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
    arr.push(document.getElementById('textbox').value); // add textbox value to array
    document.getElementById('textbox').value = ''; // clear textbox value
};

document.getElementById('view').onclick = function() {
    alert(arr.join(', ')); // alert array contents as a string; elements are delimited by ', '
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First you'll want to create your array in the global scope - this means outside of a method body, somewhere in the `<script></script>` body:

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

Next, you'll want to append the array with a new value each time the user clicks a button:

```
function myButtonClick(){
    var myTb = document.getElementById("textBox1");
    myArray.push(myTb.value);
    myTb.value = ""; // reset the textbox
}
```

Next, you'll want another button handler for the click on "View All":

```
function myViewAllButtonClick(){
   // will create a string of myArray's values, seperated by new line character
   var msg = myArray.join("\n");
   // will show the user all of the values in a modal alert
   alert(msg);
}
```

Your HTML might look like:

```
<input type="text" id="textBox1" />
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add Value" onclick="myButtonClick();"/>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Show All" onclick="myViewAllButtonClick();"/>
```

When you get the hang of things, you can get rid of the "Add Value" button all together and use:

```
<input type="text" id="textBox1" onchange="onTextChanged(this)"/>
```

With a handler like:

```
function onTextChanged(e){
    if(e.value == "") return;
    myArray.push(e.value);
    e.value = "";
}
```

The onTextChanged handler will fire when the user changes text in the textbox (it won't fire though until the textbox loses focus, which may make it bad for this example, but still a good JS skill to learn/understand).

Happy coding - good luck!

B

Comment: Technically, you want to _avoid_ having variables in global scope. But just take all the JS, and wrap it in `(function() { ... }());` and you're done

Comment: @Flambino - fully agreed - didn't want to overcomplicate things for the newbee.  Hopefully she'll read your comment and post another question about scoping :)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript array could be dynamicaly changed:

```
var array = [];

function foo() {
  array.push('foo');
}

function boo() {
  array.push('boo');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i put together a small example: http://jsbin.com/izumeb/3

```
<p><input type="text" id="txt"></input><button onclick="addToAll();">add to selection</button></p> 
<p><button onclick="showAll();">show all</button></p> 
<p id="all"></p>
```

and JS

```
<script> 
var values = [];

function addToAll() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
  values.push(txt.value);

  txt.value = "";
}

function showAll() {
  var all = document.getElementById("all");
  var str = "";
  for (var i=0;i<values.length;++i) {
    str += values[i] + "<br/>";
  }

  all.innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```